# How to fill a div with dots automatically

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am building a react app and I want to know what is the best way to fill a div with dots, to be more specific how to fill a div entirely with small rounded divs, but no matter the width of the screen the div is always full with small rounded divs.

The end result should look like this :

[image: How it should look like]

I tried to use `Array.fill().map()` but when the width of my screen changes the dots became unorganized.

My code :

```
function About() {

    const service = [
        {
            icon: <PhoneCallbackIcon style={{ fontSize: 32 }} />,
            text: "Inbound Call Center Service",
            subText: "Read more"
        },
        {
            icon: <QuestionAnswerIcon style={{ fontSize: 32 }} />,
            text: "Schriftbeschreibung",
            subText: "Read more"
        },
        {
            icon: <GTranslateIcon style={{ fontSize: 32 }} />,
            text: "Übersetzung",
            subText: "Read more"
        }
    ]

    const dots = 266

  return (
    <Container>

        <OurJob>

            <Title>Was machen wir?</Title>

            <Line />

            <p>Wir sind Experten in diesen Bereichen</p>
            
        </OurJob>
        
        <OurServices>
            
            {service.map((item, index) => (
                <Service key={index} >

                    {item.icon}

                    <div>
                       {item.text} 
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        {item.subText}
                    </p>

                </Service>
            ))}

        </OurServices>

        <Dots >

            {Array(dots).fill().map((_, i) => (
                <Dot />
            ))}

        </Dots>

    </Container>
  )
}
```

My styled components :

```
const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5% 0;
    box-shadow: 9px 11px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 11px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 9px 11px 17px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
`

const Dots = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    left: -4%;
    bottom: -25%;
`

const Dot = styled.div`
    width: 4px;
    content: "";
    height: 4px;
    margin: 5px 5.5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.5); */
    background: black;

`

const OurJob = styled.div`
    width: 25%;
    padding: 40px;
    background: rgba(122, 223, 210, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 16px 0 0 16px;
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: white;
    }
`

const Line = styled.div`
    height: 8px;
    background: white;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10px 0;
`

const Title = styled.div`
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
`

const OurServices = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 70%;
`

const Service = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;

    div {
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 600;
        height: 20%;
    }

    p {
        color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 1);
        font-size: 20px;
    }
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by setting a div with a background image and use a URL that's an encoded svg as follows:

```css
.dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='20' width='20'%3E%3Ccircle cx='10' cy='10' r='5' fill='%23e0e0e0' /%3E%3C/svg%3E ");
}
```

```html
<div class='dots'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create it without svg image on the body or your container.

You can play with the `background-size` to add/remove space between the dots.

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.5) 4px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}
```